# How to do month subtraction operation in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

i want to subtract MONTH in my table in MySQL

I hope the result is like this

| A | B | COUNTER(B - A) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19/07/2022 | 19/07/2022 | 1 |
| 09/07/2022 | 19/07/2022 | 0 |
| 06/07/2022 | 15/08/2022 | 1 |
| 14/08/2022 | 15/08/2022 | 0 |
| 19/07/2022 | 19/08/2022 | 2 |

The conclusion is date sum(month B - month A)

but if month A = month B then the value is 1

and if the month is the same but the date is less than month B then the count does not increase

Comment: Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, date_1, date_2)` - it returns **complete months** difference.

Comment: @Akina I did it but SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (month, '2022-03-20', '2022-03-20') as counter, the result it 0 but my expected result it 1

Comment: Youe need is not clear. It seems that you want to add 1 month when the day component is equal, is it?